# CURDATE(), now(), sysdate() showing yesterday's date when run in Mysql

Tags: mysql

CURDATE(), now(), sysdate() all of them are showing yesterdays date which is causing to show wrong results in the system.

Below is the screenshot for the query in MySQL and its result
[query and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yH7D.png)

Can someone indicate as to why this is happening?

Comment: Query reports MySQL server's datetime whereas the tray provides client's datetime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql)

Comment: Query returns the time of the MySQL server. The server might be running in different timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the MySql server date time settings, as query is returning **server`s *date time*.**